# What wrong with my dispatch_async for load heavy data

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

Using webservices C#, i want to display information about the product. To load data, i using dispatch_async to execute as a queue as the follows:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    //Show loading
    [ShareAppDelegate showloading];
    //LOAD PRODUCT INFO
    productDatasources = [self loadProductInfo];
    //LOAD COMMENT
    commentDatasources = [self loadComment];
    //LOAD PRODUCT PHOTOS
    photoDatasources = [self loadPhotos];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [ShareAppDelegate hideloading];
        //UPDATE PRODUCT INFO TO UI
        [self showProductInfoWithDatasource:productDatasources];
        //UPDATE COMMENT INFO TO UI
        [self showCommentWithDatasource:commentDatasources];
        //UPDATE PHOTO INFO TO UI
        [self showProductPhotoWithDatasource:photoDatasources];
     });
});
```

But sometimes it work ok, i mean, my ProductInfo, Comment and Photos could loaded and show on my screen. But sometimes, only ProductInfo could be loaded, Comment and Photos could not load and get null. And sometimes, 3 are null.

I founded that, in all cases i have tested, server always returns the result correctly, the result not null. But my dispatch_get_main_queue seem to executed before the data was received completely.

Is anybody know about my situation. Is the dispatch_async suitable. Tks in advance.

**EDIT:**

I have found the way to solve this problem. Because of in another the view, i declared and initiated NSTimer to call the another webservices. This webservice each 5 second run to notify to user if have any notification from server.

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 target:self selector:@selector(loadNotification:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

So, in this case, sometimes i have called 2 webservices and receive data same time, it the reason the GCD could not receive data correctly. Could i update notification and still execute the above GCD correctly??

Comment: Try move [ShareAppDelegate showloading]; before your dispatch_async or put it in the main thread (I assume it do some work with UI).

Comment: I have just tried to do that but it still get the same problem.

Comment: Are you sure when your main queue is called you have your product, comments and photos data?

Comment: That is the reason i use GCD to load heavy data. To make sure that the main queue have my product, comments and photos data.

Answer (score 2):

The properties you're assigning in the background thread (productDataSources, commentDataSources, photoDataSources), how are they declared? Are they accessed *anywhere* else? In that case, it might be what's wrong.

Properties that's used by the main thread must never be changed by a background thread, which is what I suspect is happening here. Instead, use temp variables on the background thread then change the real ones when you're back on the main thread, like this:

```
//Show loading on main thread (important)
[ShareAppDelegate showloading];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    //LOAD PRODUCT INFO
    NSArray *tempProductDatasources = [self loadProductInfo];
    //LOAD COMMENT
    NSArray *tempCommentDatasources = [self loadComment];
    //LOAD PRODUCT PHOTOS
    NSArray *tempPhotoDatasources = [self loadPhotos];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        // Set the temp variables when on the main thread
        productDatasources = tempProductDatasources;
        // ... etc

        [ShareAppDelegate hideloading];
        //UPDATE PRODUCT INFO TO UI
        [self showProductInfoWithDatasource:productDatasources];
        //UPDATE COMMENT INFO TO UI
        [self showCommentWithDatasource:commentDatasources];
        //UPDATE PHOTO INFO TO UI
        [self showProductPhotoWithDatasource:photoDatasources];
     });
});
```

Comment: In fact, everything i do same your code. Could you help to solve my situation that i editted above?

Comment: I guess since the NSTimer fires on the main thread, you need to queue a new background update after you receive such a notification.

Comment: Correct, in my NSTimer, i use another GCD to load data and get_main_queue to update UI.